# Unresolved reference for button id in MainActivity.kt

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, button, android-activity, reference

when I try to directly type the button id in main activity of kotlin , it does not pick it up automatically, instead it says unresolved reference, what is wrong with Android Studio??

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the same problem and have solved it this way with Android Studio 4.x:

Put this in your apps build.gradle or build.gradle.kts. The latter in my case because my project is made with Kotlin KMM.

```
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding = true
}
```

Here is my complete build.gradle.kts so you can see where it belongs to:

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")

}

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":shared"))
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.4")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.4")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "************************"
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }

}
```

Here you can read all about it. Also if you are using Android Studio lower than 4.x how it has to be done.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Don't forget to sync your project. It will only appear after that step. You can check it by having a look at dataBinding folder which you will find at that path.

**build > generated > data_binding_base_class_source_out > debug > out > rest is app specific**

and the last folder will be "**dataBinding**" folder.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to advise anything without being given any code.

I'm guessing you're using Kotlin synthetic import? Then you would also need to import something like this `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*` to be able to use view elements without `findById`. Also, make su you have integrated Kotlin extensions plugin.

Also, I can't rule out this possibility, since I can't see any of your code, but maybe check if the view element you're trying to access in `MainActivity` is in it's layout?