# Unresolved reference for objects from activity_main.xml in kotlin (Android Studio)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I'm following a kotlin / android tutorial and encountered a problem where I'm not able to reference anything by the id. Here in this example Android Studio gives me "Unresolved reference for btnDatePicker. I found this post on SO [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933717/unresolved-reference-for-button-id-in-mainactivity-kt) where the solution suggests to add the line `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`. Unfortunately I'm getting "unresolved reference" for kotlinx.

Data: Android Studio 4.1.3 Build #Al-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 11, 2021

Here is my code. I highlighted the line with the unresolved reference with `//??`

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.simpleageinminutescalc

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.content_main.* //??

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener{ Toast.makeText(this,"Button works!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="CALCULATE YOUR"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="AGE"
    android:textColor="@color/ageTextColor"
    android:background="@color/ageBackgroundColor"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="IN MINUTES"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnDatePicker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/fadedColor"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Select Date"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSelectedDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:textColor="#844046"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Selected Date"
    android:textColor="@color/fadedColor"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvSelectedDateInMinutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:textColor="#844046"
    android:textSize="35sp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:text="Age in minutes"
    android:textColor="@color/fadedColor"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what the import does in this case. If enabled, Android Studio generates 'synthetic classes' which hold references to the views in your layouts. This approach has since been deprecated, but even if you did want to use it, there are things than need to enabled in order for the synthetic classes to be generated in the first place. You can't just add a random import.

Comment: You might want to look into either `findViewById`, which is the standard way of obtaining a view reference from an ID, or look into databinding/viewbinding which is a more modern, scalable approach.

Comment: Oh ok, didn't know that is deprecated. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Documentation is here if it helps: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Comment: @HenryTwist Nice, thanks! Want to answer?

Comment: [How to fix “Unresolved reference ” error in Kotlin Android Studio 4.1 kotlin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWpdsS5Jkvo) _this video may help you_